# PHP Populate Dropdown with Unique SQL Values Quickly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website I'm working on where I want to populate 3-5 (let's say 3 for now) drop down boxes with unique values from a specific column in an SQL database.

Let's say I have

```
first   last   city
```

As my 3 drop downs to be populated.

Right now, I am doing something along the lines in my PHP of

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `first` FROM `profile` ORDER BY `first` ASC;";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $options1=$options1."<option>$row[0]</option>";
}
```

I do this then, two more times, for 'last' and 'city', populating $options2 and $options3 respectively.

The issue is, my database is going to be rather large.  10-100 Million rows large.  When I load my page, this page takes several minutes to load.  Is there something I can do to speed this up, so my main page doesn't take several minutes to load?

Comment: Your query won't work because the single quotes are being used incorrectly.  I don't know if that is the problem you are facing, but I'm tempted to close the question as a simple typo.

Comment: I just have a typo, the query I have works in my code, just takes forever.

Comment: I feel like you'd still fall into other issues as your drop-down would be very large, maybe add a searchable dropdown to prevent this - speeding it up could be done by only grabbing when user searches.

Comment: Bottom line, you need to limit the amount of data you're retrieving / showing at any one time.

Comment: So you're suggesting, by default, not populating the drop downs.  Then say, as the user types in "To" it would real-time populate the drop down with "Tom, Tonya, Tony, Toppo" etc?

Comment: Yes - although it might be an idea to withold auto-suggest until the user reaches 3 characters.

Comment: you must normalize your table structure

Comment: The query, I think, finishes fairly quickly. I had a similar problem with a huge list: the delay was in the browser, as parsing and rendering the page took ages.